# Limiting low bitrates with iw on ath9k

Tags: wireless-networking, linux

I am trying to prevent low (legacy, B) bitrates to associate with my AP, using ath9k and `iw`. I think I should run:

```
iw wlan0 set bitrates legacy-2.4 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54 ht-mcs-2.4 lgi-2.4
```

But is this correct? Will this limit legacy 2.4 bitrates, but allow all HT ones? Or should I specify all of them? So something like:

```
iw wlan0 set bitrates legacy-2.4 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54 ht-mcs-2.4 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 lgi-2.4
```

But then the question is how I can know which one I can list on a particular device.

Comment: From my testing it seems you have to list all of them. At least with recent OpenWrt. I was using old firmware and since the upgrade all connections were really bad which lead me back to this my script.

Comment: Currently it works correctly if I do `iw wlan0 set bitrates legacy-2.4 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54`. So it seems I do not have to list all HT bitrates, but I should not even mention `ht-mcs-2.4`.

Answer (score 1):

So, after the discussion on the mailing list, this is how it works.

This effectively disables CCK (11b) rates, leaves OFDM (11g),
and leaves HT rates untouched (i.e. allows HT to be used):

```
iw wlanX set bitrates legacy-2.4 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54
```

This command basically disables HT rates since it says
"ht-mcs-2.4" but specifies no MCS indexes to use, so you probably do not want to use it (I am listing it here just because it was something I tried and learned that it does not work, but I have seen it around on the Internet):

```
iw wlanX set bitrates legacy-2.4 6 9 12 18 24 36 48 54 ht-mcs-2.4 lgi-2.4
```

To reset bitrates to normal you need to issue:

```
iw wlanX set bitrates
```

So instead of listing all MCS, it is better simply to not even mention "ht-mcs-2.4".

Comment: To confirm `iw dev wlan0 set bitrates legacy-2.4 ht-mcs-2.4 4  lgi-2.4` should limit my data rate to the MCS Index #4 as per here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009#Data_rates - yes?